# Make the search box return results from all Stack Overflowian sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, user-interface, stack-exchange

There should be an easy way to search Server Fault from Stack Overflow (and the others)

The easiest thing would be to add a "Try searching Server Fault" link next to the "Alternately, try your search in Google:" on the no-results page, but this wouldn't help with overlapping searches..

For example, searching for `[sql] error 1234` might have better results of Server Fault, but a programmer might only searching SO for such a problem (a reasonable thing to do)

Maybe there could be a SO/SF/SU/Meta buttons at the top of the search results, which jump you between sites?

Since the user may not be logged into Server Fault, I guess it'd be best to display the results on the current site (with the different colour scheme maybe?), obviously all the links would go to the correct site (`http://serverfault.com/questions/...` in the example image).

A good example of such a feature is Google.

Comment: nice mockup, dbr!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was implemented at http://stackexchange.com (though it searches *all* sites in the network)

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Here, use this:

http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=018205968162215846785:ge5giybfqde

Comment: That's not particularly obvious for "regular" or new users, and it misses some of the SO search features like (easily) finding specific [tag] and so on..

Answer (score 2):

I was just thinking that this would be a great feature, while I was looking for a topic that spans both SO and SF, while I accept that I could google to search over both sites, I think that such a feature would be useful because:

1. First time users would be alerted that there is another sister site they can search on.
2. It would allow dups on topics that could possibly be on either site
3. Lazy people like me could just search in one place :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the [Stack Overflow Custom Search](http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=018205968162215846785:ge5giybfqde) (including all of SO, SF, and MSO) into your Firefox Search Box:

[Search all of Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Meta simultaneously from Firefox](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Custom-Search-Engine-to-Firefox%27s-Search-Bar-(Windows-Version))

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  Too bad we can't get a search that outputs in SO format, instead of Google format.