# Search over Stack Overflow and Server Fault at the same time?

Tags: feature-request, search, integration

As there is heated discussion as to where some edge case questions should end up, there is similar confusion on my part as to where I should search for answers to particular problems.

Is there any thought being put to have an integrated search that will pull results from whichever one of the trilogy the question has been asked?

This may also be useful to drive knowledge of the various strands of SuperStackFault to people that don't follow the place that closely.

Comment: This has already been suggested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some custom google searches out there where you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea - I'm not aware of any way to search two sites at once using `site:` with Google.

[Serverfault Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/35739/searching-two-sites-at-once-using-google)