# Search all stack overflow networked sites

Tags: discussion, search

Nowhere near as impressive as all the Greasemonkey scripts and custom parsings that are out there, I did take a few moments to follow The TXI's suggestion over in the blog and use Google Custom Search to create a quick search engine for the SO network. Afterall, I think Jeff himself has said that searching Google is a great way to get at some of the questions in there.

If anybody is interested in collaborating or anything to make the CSE work better, please let me know and I'll be happy to add you to the collaboration control panel.

The "hard" link is:
http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=004055899985439311584:twnxsyrgj4a

though I have a "friendlier" redirect setup for now by going to:
http://sofum.dillieodigital.net

Hope this helps some folks out there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

implemented at http://stackexchange.com (though it searches *all* sites in the network)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[**Joel Coehoorn ♦**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) already [**did this back in June**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites/917#917) in the question "[Make the search box return results from all StackOverflowian sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites)"

Comment: Well DOH! I should have checked back over there first, or used my own newly created search. I thought all of the "tools" and such posts had been migrated here already.