# search on all the stackoverflow related sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the search box return results from all StackOverflowian sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites)

Is there, or should there be a mega search - that can search stackoverflow and all it's sister sites? - As a person who has interests and needs in all of the sites, this would be useful to me, because let's face it, people don't always post where they should.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879

Comment: this discusses how to search all sites via google: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10551

Comment: The google search yshuditelu posted the link to works nice, but we still need a search that outputs in SO format like his first link instead of Google format.

Comment: http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=018205968162215846785:ge5giybfqde

Answer (score 1):

This will sound cheeky, but seriously, there is one. It is called www.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

If people aren't posting where they should, the community will quickly migrate it appropriately, so I don't think that should be a concern.

You'd be better off searching individually or using google to filter by site ("site:stackoverflow.com" for example).