# How can I search across all sites for topics

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if I could create a tag list and/or keywords that would create a pool of questions I may be able to answer or flag as something I can't.

But as it is how can I do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Right now there isn't a network wide search, if that's the main part of your feature request then you should upvote this earlier proposal: [Make the search box return results from all StackOverflowian sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/make-the-search-box-return-results-from-all-stackoverflowian-sites)

However, you can create a [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) on stackexchange.com, and include any tag you want, from any site (no keywords though).

Comment: I don't quite agree with the _isn't a network wide search_ part. I think there is a way to do that from SE.com

Comment: @Starx That's a custom google search, there's a difference. The search results in your screenshot show how useless that search is...

Answer (score 2):

You can go to [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) and use the search box there. Here is an illustration

[image: Showing Network Wide Searching]

The screenshot is showing the results from two SE Sites.